# How to remove a part of stdout of a running shell script based on starting and ending strings?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, stdout

I have a shell script in which other scripts are called, where new processes are created. There is a certain part of that output logs that i don't want to see on the screen, since it s excessive. If this was a text file, i could remove that part using the following line:

`sed 's/String1.*String2//g'`

However, i guess when running a script (continuous logs) or even receiving the logs through cat tool, the logs are send line by line with EOF. Hence sed can not track the regular expression.
Long story short, i want to be able to do this to shorten the stdout of the test run:

`./test1 | sed 's/String1.*String2//g'`

and as a result can get rid of almost 200 redundant lines of logs on the output screen.

Comment: A short test with `cat` as well `tail -F` with `${FILENAME}.log | sed '/String1/,/String2/d'` seemed to be working.

Comment: Hang on... Your example command will not get rid of *any* lines-- it can at most make them blank. Are you talking about `String1` and `String2` being on separate lines?

Comment: Yes they're on different lines, and i found the answer: awk '/String1/{flag=1} /String2/{flag=0} !flag'